# Is it possible to replace Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul with Spring Cloud Gateway in an Spring MVC App?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a Spring Boot App, that uses Spring Cloud Zuul.
Zuul is used for routing and for filters of the types PRE, POST, ROUTE and ERROR.
Because of the EOL of Zuul I want to switch to another framework.

Spring names Spring Cloud Gateway as replacement https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode.
According to the documentation, Spring Cloud Gateway does not work with a MVC app. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#gateway-starter.

But there is existing a subproject of Spring Gateway named spring-cloud-gateway-mvc and a short part in the documenation about MVC which confuses me (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#building-a-simple-gateway-by-using-spring-mvc-or-webflux).
I did not manage to rebuild the existing filters that way.

What is the best way to go to replace Zuul in the application? Is there a way to get Spring Cloud Gateway running with the MVC app or are there better alternatives?